# Angularjs Unable to show (display) the values set in the controller on view

Tags: angularjs

I am getting an error message from a HTTP call, in the error block of the 
  async call, I have to show the same message on the view, so I took the
  message in the scope variable like below:

```
$scope.errMessage = "error messsage"
```

In the view same variable name is used as `{{errMessage}}`
but I couldn't see the message being displayed could someone help me?
Is there anything to do for async calls for displaying the results either
success or error.

```
  Below is the controller part of the call

  ContactService.getUser(searchByNum).then(function(success){
          console.log("success"+JSON.stringify(success.data.errCode));
      },function(error, status, headers, config){

          **$scope.errMessages = error.data.errMessage;**
          console.log("error"+JSON.stringify(error.data.errMessage));
   })



    Below is the service part of the actual http call

    this.getUser = function(searchByNum){
    return $http({ method: 'GET', 
    url: 'http://localhost:8083/simpro1/helloRest/user/'+searchByNum});
   }
```

Comment: Post your call please - the above code isn't enough to help

Comment: Post the code would help, if not, try the following route to help you get an idea what actually has gone wrong.  I would first start with assigning `$scope.errMessage = 'test'` from the get go, so the template should at least show "test".  Next, I would put a `console.log("errMessage set")` right where the error happens.  Then open up browser console window to see if the code has ever reached there.

Comment: Your code states "$scope.errMessages" but your interpolation is {{errMessage}}.  Is this simply a typo?

Comment: @RamblinRose , no its not a typo , we need not include $scope for variables of controller in view

Comment: can somebody tell me how to write the same service call with promises ?